# IndexOutOfBoundsException showing while running my android program

Tags: android, android-mapview, indexoutofboundsexception, runtimeexception

I am doing an Android map oriented project. I wrote some code to display the direction between two places, but it only works in lower android versions such as 2.0, 2.2, etc. It is not working on Android 4.0 and higher. When I run this code in Android 4.0 it shows an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**My class**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class LocationActivity extends MapActivity {
        MapView mv;

        MapController mc;

        Button Save, Cancel;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.map_places);
                MapView mv = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
                mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                MapController mc = mv.getController();
                ArrayList<GeoPoint> all_geo_points = getDirections(10.154929, 76.390316, 10.015861, 76.341867);
                GeoPoint moveTo = all_geo_points.get(0);
                mc.animateTo(moveTo);
                mc.setZoom(12);
                mv.getOverlays().add(new MyOverlay(all_geo_points));
        }

        public class MyOverlay extends Overlay {
                private ArrayList<GeoPoint> all_geo_points;

                public MyOverlay(ArrayList<GeoPoint> allGeoPoints) {
                        super();
                        this.all_geo_points = allGeoPoints;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mv, boolean shadow, long when) {
                        super.draw(canvas, mv, shadow);
                        drawPath(mv, canvas);
                        return true;
                }

                public void drawPath(MapView mv, Canvas canvas) {
                        int xPrev = -1, yPrev = -1, xNow = -1, yNow = -1;
                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
                        paint.setAlpha(100);
                        if (all_geo_points != null) for (int i = 0; i < all_geo_points.size() - 4; i++) {
                                GeoPoint gp = all_geo_points.get(i);
                                Point point = new Point();
                                mv.getProjection().toPixels(gp, point);
                                xNow = point.x;
                                yNow = point.y;
                                if (xPrev != -1) {
                                        canvas.drawLine(xPrev, yPrev, xNow, yNow, paint);
                                }
                                xPrev = xNow;
                                yPrev = yNow;
                        }
                }
        }

        public static ArrayList<GeoPoint> getDirections(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
                String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" + lat1 + "," + lon1 + "&destination=" + lat2 + "," + lon2
                                + "&sensor=false&units=metric";
                String tag[] = {"lat", "lng"};
                ArrayList<GeoPoint> list_of_geopoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
                        if (doc != null) {
                                NodeList nl1, nl2;
                                nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag[0]);
                                nl2 = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag[1]);
                                if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
                                        list_of_geopoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                                                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                                                Node node2 = nl2.item(i);
                                                double lat = Double.parseDouble(node1.getTextContent());
                                                double lng = Double.parseDouble(node2.getTextContent());
                                                list_of_geopoints.add(new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6)));
                                        }
                                } else {
                                        // No points found
                                }
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return list_of_geopoints;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
        }
}
```

**My logcat**

```
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kodspider.parkon/com.kodspider.parkon.LocationActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1900)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at com.kodspider.parkon.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:43)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-01 19:05:19.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     ... 18 more
```

Comment: `getDirections()` seems to be returning an empty ArrayList.

Comment: you are right but it can run on low platforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question for higher version of android platforms we must use an AsyncTask class for the background thread

Comment: For lower versions you should use AsyncTasks too.

Answer (score 3):

So, basically, getDirections() is returning an empty ArrayList, and then you're trying to access its first item.

Try to understand why is your method returning an empty set and fix that.

Comment: it will not return empty list of array in low platforms like 2.2,2.0

Comment: Well, then fix THAT. The ArrayOutOfBoundsException is a consequence, not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You got the exception at
com.kodspider.parkon.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:43)

I assume it is following line of code:

```
ArrayList<GeoPoint> all_geo_points = getDirections(10.154929, 76.390316, 10.015861, 76.341867);
GeoPoint moveTo = all_geo_points.get(0);
```

So the Method getDirections is returning an empty array.
try:

```
 if(all_geo_points.size()>0){
    GeoPoint moveTo = all_geo_points.get(0);
    mc.animateTo(moveTo);
    mc.setZoom(12);
    mv.getOverlays().add(new MyOverlay(all_geo_points));
}
```

Comment: ok now i got map but it is not getting any value to array list

Comment: thats another Problem. Look at your getDirections() returns an empty array... don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code...

```
public static JSONObject getLocationInfo(String origin, String dest) {

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

try {
        origin = origin.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        dest = dest.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="
                        + origin + "&destination=" + dest + "&sensor=false");
        // http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&sensor=false

        Log.i("httppost",
                "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="
                        + origin + "&destination=" + dest + "&sensor=false");

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        response = client.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        Log.i("Ex1", e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("Ex2", e.getMessage());
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

        Log.i("JSON Length", "" + jsonObject.length());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```